# FPDF object has no attribute 'epw'

Tags: python, fpdf, pyfpdf, fpdf2

I want to create a table using the 'FPDF' library, but python gives me an error
**'CreateTablePDF' object has no attribute 'epw'**
There is my code:

```
import pathlib
from os.path import join

from fpdf import FPDF


class CreateTablePDF(FPDF):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CreateTablePDF, self).__init__()
        src_dir = f'{pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent.absolute()}'

        font_dir = join(src_dir, 'common', 'fonts')
        font_arial = join(font_dir, "arial.ttf")

        self.add_font("Arial", "", font_arial, uni=True)
        self.set_font("Arial", size=8)

    def create_table_from_rows(self, rows):
        once = True
        line_height = self.font_size * 1.5
        col_width = self.epw / 3
        for row in rows:
            for datum in row:
                if datum != None:
                    if once:
                        self.set_fill_color(230, 230, 230)
                        self.multi_cell(col_width, line_height, datum, border=1, ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size, fill=True)
                    else:
                        self.multi_cell(col_width, line_height, datum, border=1, ln=3, max_line_height=self.font_size)
                    col_width = self.epw / 3
            once = False
            col_width = self.epw / 10
            self.ln(line_height)
```

I tried to install 'FPDF2', but it never worked, although it is in the class that is installed on my computer, here

```
def __init__(
    self,
    orientation: _Orientation = ...,
    unit: _Unit | float = ...,
    format: _Format | tuple[float, float] = ...,
    font_cache_dir: str | Literal["DEPRECATED"] = ...,
) -> None: ...
...
def epw(self) -> float: ...
@property
...
```

(I apologize for my poor English, I used Google translator)

Comment: a small correction 
...
@property                                                                                                                                                              
def epw(self) -> float: ...
...

Comment: Please check; https://github.com/bvalgard/create-pdf-with-python-fpdf2/issues/2

Comment: I checked, it is not working

Comment: Click the 'Edit' button to make the correction to your question, don't add the correction as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

`.epw` & `.eph` properties only appeared in version 2.3.0 of `fpdf2`: https://github.com/py-pdf/fpdf2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#230---2021-01-29

Make sure that you have installed the latest version of `fpdf2`:

```
pip install --upgrade fpdf2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the 'epw' variable does not exist in the FPDF ParentClass, but you can easily define the 'epw' attribute in the **init** method of your CreateTablePDF class.

```
import pathlib
from os.path import join
from fpdf import FPDF

class CreateTablePDF(FPDF):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CreateTablePDF, self).__init__()
        src_dir = f'{pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent.absolute()}'
        font_dir = join(src_dir, 'common', 'fonts')
        font_arial = join(font_dir, "arial.ttf")
        self.add_font("Arial", "", font_arial, uni=True)
        self.set_font("Arial", size=8)
        # NEW
        self.page_width = self.w - 2 * 1.5 #how much it is up to you
        self.epw = self.page_width / 3
```

OK, even after solving the "epw" problem, there are other errors in your code.
In sequence:

1. No page open, you need to call add_page() first
2. TypeError: FPDF.multi_cell() got two unexpected keyword argument 'ln' and 'max_line_height' (even if they seem to exist in the definition)

Therefore, I have changed your snippet to make it work.
Here's my version, in which I simply create a pdf file containing a table with 'ciao','hello','hola' in its 3 rows.

```
    def create_table_from_rows(self, rows):
        once = True
        line_height = self.font_size * 1.5
        col_width = self.epw / 3

        self.add_page() #add a new page before creating the table

        for row in rows:
            for datum in row:
                if datum != None:
                    if once:
                        self.set_fill_color(230, 230, 230)
                        self.multi_cell(col_width, line_height, datum, border=1, fill=True)
                    else:
                        self.multi_cell(col_width, line_height, datum, border=1)
                col_width = self.epw / 3
            once = False
            col_width = self.epw / 10
            self.ln(line_height)

        

a = CreateTablePDF()
a.create_table_from_rows((['ciao','hello','hola'],))
a.output('table.pdf', 'F')
```

N.B. If you want to insert numbers into the table, your class method is not correct, you should modify it, to avoid this common AttributeError:
'int' object has no attribute 'replace'in line => s=txt.replace("\r",'') of /your_python_lib_path_/fpdf/fpdf.py

```
    def create_table_from_rows(self, rows):
        once = True
        line_height = self.font_size * 1.5
        col_width = self.epw / 3
        self.add_page() 
        for row in rows:
            for datum in row:
                if datum is not None:
                     self.set_fill_color(230, 230, 230)
                     txt = str(datum) #convert to a string
                     self.multi_cell(col_width, line_height, txt.replace("\r", ""), border=1) #remove any carriage returns (\r) using the replace() method.
                else:
                    self.multi_cell(col_width, line_height, "", border=1) #without 'ln' and 'max_line_height' for now
                col_width = self.epw / 3
            once = False
            col_width = self.epw / 10
            self.ln(line_height)

a = CreateTablePDF()
a.create_table_from_rows(([1,2,3],))
a.output('table_nums.pdf', 'F')
```

You can start from here to design your custom table. Bye!